# Is there a way to group by part of a datetime column in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a dataframe something like this.

```
Time                           DollarVal
2020-06-25 17:48:13.636          1000
2020-06-27 17:48:13.895          1000
2020-06-27 17:48:14.101          1000
2020-06-24 17:48:14.434          1000
2020-06-22 17:48:14.709          1000
```

is there a way to return a table that sums the dollar values based on the time down to the minute.
For example:

```
Time          DollarVal
17:48:13        2000
17:48:14        3000
```

Notice that the "time" data in the original data set spans over a few days but I am only concerned with the time of day.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to just extract the time, but you can format it as a string:

```
select format_datetim(time, '%H:%i:%s') as time_only, sum(dollarval)
from t
group by time_only
order by time_only;
```

Or, you can just convert the value to a time (subject to Piotr's comment):

```
select cast(time as time) as time_only, . . .
```

Comment: `CAST(time AS time)` ;)

Comment: I know. I am just observing that for a `time` column of type `timestamp`, `CAST(time AS time)` is a valid expression, converting it to a `time` data type (preserving time-of-day).

Comment: Note that we fixed some bugs around this conversions around Presto 337, so disregard the advice if running on an older version.